# Create a blank file in existing Google Drive Folder - V3 - PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a blank spreadsheet inside an existing folder (i.e. inside **GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID**) but my code seems to ignore the folder ID and keeps creating the blank spreadsheet in the root of my Google Drive instead of creating the blank file inside the folder as indicated by:

```
$file->setParents('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID');
```

Below is more code for context:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE, Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);

...

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setParents('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID');
$file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet');
$file->setName('Test File');

$results = $service->files->create($file);
```

I can't find any proper PHP code sample documentation for the **Google Drive API V3**.
Is this possibly a permission issue?

I would love some help as I have been struggling with this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your scopes can be used for your situation. But I think that `setParents('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID')` is required to be modified. `parents` is 1 dimensional array. So how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
$file->setParents('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID');
```

#### To:

```
$file->setParents(array('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID'));
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)